# How do I mute speakers, but have sound in headphones?

Tags: sound, headphones

I don't have any app that even recognizes my headphones. I would like to find a simple app that has a master volume level and then a volume level for all output devices, including headphones. I've tried qasmixer and the gnome mixer, but they don't seem to recognize headphones, nor are they quite as simple as I would like. I want a simple panel app.

Comment: Tried alsamixer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pavucontrol? You can edit any input source or output source in it including the volume from each program playing sound.